# Is there a way to encapsulate native dependencies in single package for React Native?

Tags: react-native

In my own react-native package I use several dependencies with platform native code like...

```
react-native-vector-icons
react-native-fetch-blob
react-native-orientation
... others
```

Currently in my App I have to link all these packages.

Is there any way to link only my package in react-native App and not to link all others?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. They way I am doing it right now is that I have a git dependency in my package.json like this:

"core-module": "git+https://username:readOnlyPassword@yourcloneurl"

All the dependencies that you have in that package should automatically install if you select them as package depednencies in your core module.

Keep in mins this won't link the modules in Android and iOS. That is a manual task. I believe this can be automated too with gradle and node but I havent done it yet.

Good luck

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But my question is exactly about linking modules in Android and iOS. I want that user of my package had to deal with only my package and doesn't need to link some third-parties modules.